# Bash restore database MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash

My bash: testing

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in    
"restore") tar xzvf $2 | mysql --password=my_password --user=my_user my_db;;
*) echo "Others";;
esac
```

Testing:

```
testing restore bckp_2013.tgz
```

Not working, show "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bckp_2013.sql' at line 1"

But this works:

```
mysql --password=my_password --user=my_user my_db < bckp_2013.sql
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in    
"restore") tar xzvf $2;
           sqlfile=$(ls -t *.sql | xargs);
           mysql --password=my_password --user=my_user my_db < $sqlfile;;
*) echo "Others";;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks David. Processing now!